# Array from a file

Tags: bash

If I have a file like this:

```
A:a
B:b
C:c
```

I need to create 2 arrays like

```
one=('A' 'B' 'C')
two=('a' 'b' 'c')
```

How can I do it in bash?

I've tried this:

```
declare -a one
declare -a two

while read line
do
    IFS=':' read -ra ADDR <<< $line
    echo ${ADDR[0]}
    echo ${ADDR[1]}
done < file.txt
```

Sorry I wrote from work and then I came home. Sorry again. The problem with this is that it's printing

```
littlelion:Documents dierre$ sh prova.sh 
A a

B b
```

so it's missing C c and I have no idea how to add an element to an array

Comment: you're not using your `declare -a one (& two)`s. Seems like that would help. Also, as you're using IFS=:, why not do `read tmpOne tmpTwo;...` AND you don't need `<<< $line`. Then do something like `one=(${one[@]} $tmpOne)`... etc, but you get to figure that out ;-) (That's why this is a comment). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes fix everything:

```
while read line
do
    IFS=':' read -ra ADDR <<< "$line"
    echo ${ADDR[0]}
    echo ${ADDR[1]}
done < file.txt
```

Quoting the variable `"$line"` is what made the difference. If you're not getting the line with "C:c", it's probably because your file is missing a final newline.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
declare -a one
declare -a two

one=( $(cut -d: -f1 file) )
two=( $(cut -d: -f2 file) )
```

`var=$(command)` captures the output of your command and assigns it to `var`.  The outer parens makes that an array assignment.  `cut -d: -f1` says to treat your file as a colon delimited file and print the first field.  `cut -d: -f2` does the same but it prints the second field.

---

<sup>Edit in response to OP's edits</sup>

You can read into `ADDR` directly like so:

```
declare -a ADDR
while IFS=':' read -a ADDR; do
  echo ${ADDR[0]}
  echo ${ADDR[1]}
done < file.txt
```

Although that won't populate arrays `one` and `two`...

Comment: This will probably work, but it would not be optimal to loop through the file twice if it is a large file.

Comment: @gpojd Highly optimized, no, but it is short.  I would prefer it for small to medium size files.

Comment: @dierre You're right, I overlooked the outer parens.  With what's there now `one` and `two` *will* be arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do properly, this should work:

```
one=()
two=()
while IFS=: read new_one new_two || [ -n "$new_one" ]; do
    one+=("$new_one")
    two+=("$new_two")
done
echo "one:" "${one[@]}"
echo "two:" "${two[@]}"
```

Note: I agree with @Dennis Williamson that the final line isn't being processed because it doesn't end with a newline; I added the `|| [ -n "$new_one" ]` bit to keep this from being a problem.