# How do I read entire lines with <<< operator?

Tags: bash

I need to validate some program output. I know the output contains exactly three lines that I would like to store in distinct variables for easy access. I tried several variations of the following without success.

```
IFS=$'\n' read line1 line2 line3 <<< $(grep pattern file.log)
IFS='' read line1 line2 line3 <<< $(grep pattern file.log)
```

Is it possible to combine `read` and `<<<` to do what I want? How?

If it is not possible, what is the explanation? What alternative do you suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758719/array-from-a-file).  It's putting the lines into an ARRAY.  From there you can re-assign to line1 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
    read line1
    read line2
    read line3
} < <(grep pattern file.log)
```

I feel that putting a command substitution (`$()`) after a herestring (`<<<`)
 is an unnecessary contortion, as is trying to trick `read` into reading more than one line at a time. This is a case where multiple `read`s in a compound command is a natural solution.

Comment: Other usages of read tricked ME into thinking I could easily read multiple lines at once ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well I have found how to make it work. It hinged on the use of double quotes.

First I tried this:

```
data=$(grep pattern file.log)
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r line1 line2 line3 <<< "$data"
```

Then found that the variable was not absolutely necessary if I kept the double quotes:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r line1 line2 line3 <<< "$(grep pattern file.log)"
```

By default, a newline indicates end of data. To avoid `read` to stop working after the first line, I override the default with `-d ''`.

By default, the field separator is `<space><tab><newline>`. Since I want to read entire lines, I set IFS to `$'\n'`.

Note that `-r` is not central to the solution. I added it to avoid stumbling on eventual backslashes in my input.

EDIT

Using `read` and `<<<` has one subtle but important drawback: blank lines will disappear entirely.

```
data="1

3"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r line1 line2 line3 <<< "$data"
echo ${line1:-blank}
echo ${line2:-blank}
echo ${line3:-blank}

output:
1
3
blank
```

Same if you try storing lines into an array with `-a`:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a line_ar <<< "$data"
echo ${line_ar[0]:-blank}
echo ${line_ar[1]:-blank}
echo ${line_ar[2]:-blank}

output:
1
3
blank
```

However, you will still obtain all lines with a construct like this:

```
while read -r line ; do
  echo ${line:-blank}
done <<< "$data"

output:

1
blank
3
```

If the number of lines is very limited, then you're better off using multiple reads as suggestd by kojiro. Then again, it is perfectly legal to use `<<<`:

```
{ 
  read -r line1
  read -r line2
  read -r line3
} <<< "$data"

echo ${line1:-blank}
echo ${line2:-blank}
echo ${line3:-blank}
```

Remember to enclose your `"$var"` inside double quotes to have newline expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Set `IFS` to `\n` and pass `-d ''` to `read`. Also you can use process substitution instead of a here string

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -d'' -r line1 line2 line3; do :; done < <(grep pattern file.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array

```
read -a array < <(grep pattern file.log)
# Optional
line1=${array[0]}
line2=${array[1]}
line3=${array[2]}
```

However, I would recommend [kojiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17578243/1126841).

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r arry[x]; do 
    ((x++)); 
done < <(grep pattern file.log)
```

This will create an array called `arry` and the 3 lines will belong to each indices starting from 0.

Comment: seems to create an extra empty element at the end of the array

Comment: Seems you need to learn about the `mapfile` builtin: `mapfile -t arry < <(grep pattern file.log)` will do just this but much more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @gniourf_gniourf, that indeed looks nice and doesn't even create an empty element at the end. Any possible downside other than being `bash 4` only?

Comment: @JS It'll be faster, but I'm not sure you can call this a downside `;)`. But you're right it's limited to Bash 4 that, in my opinion, everybody should be using `:)`.